# How parser properties in node XML file in XQUERY SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have this XML:

[image]

i want to get the value on Property name = "ParticipTypeName" i am using something like that:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT     'http://xml.common.asset.aoma.sonymusic.com/ProductMetadata.xsd')
SELECT   
    x.u.value('(/BusinessUnitProperties/Property[@name = "ParticipTypeName"])[1]', 'varchar(100)') as ParticipTypeName
from 
    @XML.nodes('/ProductMetadata/Tracks/Track/Participants/Participant') x(u)
```

it doesn't work.
How I should get the value in this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT x.u.value('(//*:Property[@*:name="ParticipTypeName"])[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

The `//` will search for **any** element `<Property>`. The `XQuery`-filter will choose the one with the name you are looking for. The `*:` will allow you to ignore the namespace.

Comment: doesn't work :XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Comment: that works, but i cannot use // will search for any element <Property>, i need to access the node BusinessUnitProperties/Property and get Property[@name = "ParticipTypeName"], can you help me? becasue the xml is too long and it has a lot of Property in different nodes

Comment: Hi Shnugo. AFAICT, the `[@*:name="ParticipTypeName"]` part is called an *XPath predicate*.